# Android replace system/lib/lib.so does not work

Tags: android, linux, shared-libraries

I want to replace a system library by one where I made some small changes. Both libraries were compiled with the same version of cyanogenmod source. The one I copied to the sdcard worked on an earlier flash of CM.

Now I try to run the following:

```
$ adb shell
shell@m0:/ $ su 
root@m0:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
root@m0:/ # chmod 777 /system/lib/libwilhelm.so
root@m0:/ # cp /sdcard/libwilhelm.so /system/lib/libwilhelm.so
root@m0:/ # chmod 644 /system/lib/libwilhelm.so
root@m0:/ # mount -o ro,remount /system
root@m0:/ # reboot
```

However even after reboot the old libwilhelm.so is used

I know this because I log something in the not-overriden version in 
`frameworks/wilhelm/src/sl_entry.c`:

```
#include <android/log.h>
 #define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "frameworks/wilhelm/src/sl_entry.c", __VA_ARGS__))

// ...

SL_API SLresult SLAPIENTRY slCreateEngine(SLObjectItf *pEngine, SLuint32 numOptions,
    const SLEngineOption *pEngineOptions, SLuint32 numInterfaces,
    const SLInterfaceID *pInterfaceIds, const SLboolean *pInterfaceRequired)
{ 


    LOGI("qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq in slCreateEngine");

 //... continue original code
```

This log is then different in the other library that is on the sdcard. So the logcat should display something else once I replaced the library and rebooted but it still prints the original log message.

Also the library doesn't seem to be read from another location:

```
root@m0:/ # find . -name "libwilhelm*"
./mnt/shell/emulated/0/libwilhelm.so
./system/lib/libwilhelm.so
find: ./proc/1897/task/2088/fd/49: No such file or directory
find: ./proc/1897/task/2088/fd/57: No such file or directory
find: ./proc/1897/task/2100/fd/42: No such file or directory
find: ./proc/2466/task/2471/fd/88: No such file or directory
find: ./proc/2466/task/2741/fd/85: No such file or directory
find: ./proc/2466/task/2741/fd/95: No such file or directory
./data/media/0/libwilhelm.so
```

What did I miss?

Comment: I'd look for other copies of the .so file elsewhere on the filesystem.  I'd especially look out for the apk itself including the .so

Comment: @Gabe Sechan : I updated the answer

Comment: How are you logging? What log level did you set when you built the library? From where are you logging (how did you verify that your log call will be executed)?

Comment: @Michael, I updated the question (not the answer, my bad) again.

Comment: Maybe this is the case because I have to edit 'system.img' instead for replacing the lib ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `frameworks/wilhelm/src/sl_entry.c` is not part of the `libwilhelm.so` but the `libOpenSLES.so`

Moreover it is safer to replace the library by an updater-script that can be executed from a recovery program like TWRP. The script could look like:

```
ui_print("mounting /system");
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/mmcblk0p9", "/system");
ui_print("/system now mounted");
ui_print("adding new shared library libOpenSLES.so");
package_extract_file("libOpenSLES.so", "/system/lib/libOpenSLES.so");
ui_print("done adding new shared library libOpenSLES.so");
ui_print("unmounting /system");
unmount("/system");
ui_print("/system now unmounted");
ui_print("finished");
```